# How to get correct DPI of display with Java, when user change the screen resolution on Windows settings?

Tags: java, windows, awt, screen-resolution, toolkit

To be able get dpi value, I am using this:

```
float dpi = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();
```

In advance display settings, When I applied **1366 x 768** as a resolution value;

`dpi` value returns `96` (That is what I expected)

However, When I changed **800 x 600** as a resolution value in settings;

`dpi` value returns `96` (That should be lower value than `96`)

When I try same case in **mac** computer, the right values are coming.

I think there is something wrong in the resolution value which comes from Windows OS. I have tested for **Windows 7** and **Windows 10**.

**Edit** : To understand why I need this value, check this question and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36626250/4606266).

Comment: What do you need the resolution and dpi for? This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: My java application scales everything to the the resolution (DPI) of the screen. This includes icons, borders, insets, custom graphics and font.

Comment: And your graphics API doesn't handle that for you?

Comment: I have editted my question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707756/how-to-correctly-detect-dpi-of-display-with-java

Comment: @Redlab I have already seen the question. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is in [official documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff716252.aspx) :

> Specifies what size to show text and other items on the screen.
>   **Windows DPI value is an integer between 96 and 480.** Supported values
>   include 96, 120, and 144. By default, Windows uses automatic DPI
>   configuration.

Thats why It returns `96` for 800 x 600.